# In Filters or Servlet to get initial info about the user when user go to the page

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have question:

Look, When user goes to my web page I want to get info about the user from his cookie or special ID which is in database and render for example hello User1 on my page when user on the page.

Where I have to perform this operations in `filter.init()` before user will request the servlet or on `servlet.init()` or would be fine to get this particular info in `servlet.doGet()`???

Thank you.
With best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you want to use filters to transform input or output, or to set up pre-conditions for your servlets.

In your particular case, because it's so simple, it probably doesn't really matter which one you choose.  *However* having filters perform authentication and authorization is very common, so you could have your filter check the cookie and / or query the database for the user information, and add it as a request attribute.  After that, have the servlet do the work of preparing or writing the message, using the prepared request attribute.  As a general rule, you don't want to *write* output in a filter.

In either case, you won't be using the `init` method of either the filter or the servlet for this task.  The `init` method is called to initialize the filter or servlet when the application server creates the object, and may or may not be called for every request (in fact, it's probably *not* called for every request).

Answer (score 0):

in your Filter , use method doFilter

```
public void  doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
             ServletResponse response,
             FilterChain chain) 
             throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {
//check cookie or anything you want
}
```

Comment: pretty much yes , just keep to heavy logic in filter , not good for performance